# How can i solve the start oracle-xe probelem?

Tags: database, oracle

[image: Error snapshot]

When I'm trying to start `oracle-xe`, I get the errors in the snapshot. I uninstalled and reinstalled the oracle many times but there is no change. The same problem. Please, any suggestions?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows? Which version? Which edition?

Comment: Looks like Linux, @APC. At least, according to my microscope.

Comment: @Littlefoot - looks like you're right. It might be helpful to know which flavour of Linux.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 0):

Under `/u01/app/oracle` or similar, you should see a folder called `diag`. Under that will be a tree of directories, two of note being `rdbms` (for the database) and `tnslsnr` (for the listener).

Under `rdbms`, keep following the `XE` folders until you find a file `alert_xe.log`.  That file might contain some clues on why the database did not start.

Under `tnslsnr`, follow the `hostname`, then the `listener` folders until you get to the `trace` folder, and the file `listener.log`. That file might have some clues on why the listener did not start.

Having said all that, if you are new to XE, I'd be looking at using 18c XE not the (very old) 11g XE. Lots easier to install, lots more robust and you get a lot more features.

And it's still 100% free.

Comment: Is the oracle-XE 18c working with Ubuntu 18.4 ?. I read some posts about that. oracle-XE 18c  is working with all Linux versions but not working with Ubuntu?. Any suggestions, please?